# Android Button in xml

Tags: android, button

i have a button which i have created in the xml document, it is in the document called Tab1.xml, this is the code in my Tab1 java file

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is Tab1");
        setContentView(textview);
    }}
```

currently i havent got a button created in my java file the code in my xml document is

```
 <Button    android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1" 
android:text="Buy" />
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: You should try to do: setContentView(R.layout.Tab1); Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonID);

Comment: You should really go through a Tutorial, try something yourself, and when you're facing a problem that you really can't solve post here. We are not here 'free-developers' that one can use. You could also put a small amount of effort when writting/formatting your question if you want somebody to help you....

Comment: Hey, have a look at this page, maybe you get things clearer. If you keep having troubles paste your code and errors clearly.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: i have been going through tutorials and i have tried something it myself, its because i have been having this trouble since yesturday,  i have a button but i dont know how to link it to another tab

Answer (score 2):

`Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonIdInyourXMLfile);`

Comment: i have inserted that code, but how do i get that button to link to the page i want?

Comment: `yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){  public void onClick(){   startActivity(new Intent(context, pageYouWant.this)); ) )};`  but yeah seriously, get a book.